# Nested IF Statement, error with column with errors

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking at data that has (1) a difference in dates in days and a product type (for this specific example, product type=F).

Currently my date column has this formula:

```
=DATEDIF([@[END]],[@[START]],"d")
```

Sometimes this data brings back "#NUM" error due to the Start Date being before the End Date (the nature of the data).

The formula I am having issue with is this:

```
=IF([PRODUCTTYPE]="F",IF([@[Day Difference b/w StartandEnd]]>100,"NO","YES"),"N/A")
```

Due to there being the #NUM error in the Date difference column, the second formula is putting those into the "NO" bucket. I want the outcome to be if the date column had a #NUM error, then this formula would also put as "N/A".

What is missing?

Comment: Just include an error handler on the first date column `=IFERROR(Value,value if error)`. Then include an IF clause in your other column to interpret whatever you put for `value if error`

Comment: Where do I input the IF clause in the other column? I keep getting a #VALUE error.

Comment: So for example in the first column use `=IFERROR(your code,"Apple")`. Then the second column would be `IF(cell="Apple","NO",rest of your code)`

Comment: Use `=IF([PRODUCTTYPE]="F",IFERROR(IF([@[Day Difference b/w StartandEnd]]>100,"NO","YES"),"N/A"),"N/A")`